# F# Get stack overflow while counting infinite sum of series

Tags: f#, stack-overflow

I made a program to count infinite [sum of series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6mSA.png)
but get an error: stack overflow. Help please

```
let sum_series (max : float) =
    let rec f (a:float, x : float) = 
        match x with
            | 0. -> a
            | x -> f ((1. / (x * x) + a), x - 1.)
    f (0., max)
 
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let (b, max) = System.Double.TryParse(args.[0])
    printfn "%A" (sum_series max)
    0
```

Comment: Does it overflow for all inputs? Can you give it an input that overflows and you think shouldn't?

Comment: Also, it looks like this is designed to work with integer values of x, since you decrement x by 1 and stop when x is 0. If so, you should type x as int. If not, you should change your stopping condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code gets into an infinite loop if you call the function with a `max` value that is not an integer. The issue is that you keep subtracting `1.0` from `max` in each step, but then you only check whether it equals `0.0` at the end. If you start with `0.1`, your next values will be `-0.9, -1.9, -2.9` etc.

Do you just want to check for a case when `x` is less then `0.0`? You can change your `match` to an ordinary `if` (which makes this simpler) and use:

```ml
let sum_series (max : float) =
  let rec f (a:float, x : float) = 
      if x < 0. then a
      else f ((1. / (x * x) + a), x - 1.)
  f (0., max)
```